# Converting String with datetime stamp with UTC to Datetime in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on an ingestion pipeline on SQL Server 2017 and a column is loaded as strings datatype but  contains datetimes datatype. I am trying to convert a string that is loaded in the following format = `2019-12-12 22:05:34.0022UTC` to a DateTime.

I tried using `CONVERT` function with `DATETIME` datatype and `DATETIME2` datatype but that is not doing the trick. If I delete .0022UTC then I am able to convert using `DATETIME` but I don't want to do that and am wondering if theres a way to capture the value as DateTime.

Comment: Have you considered using `LEFT`? Also, neither `datetime` or `datetime2` are functions, they are data types; a completely different thing. A function would be `CONVERT`, `GETDATE` or the aforementioned `LEFT`.

Comment: I meant Dataype , sorry about that.